# LaTeX build system similar to CMake

Tags: graphics, latexmk, git, build-system

Suppose I have a LaTeX repo, which contains main file and lots of image files, also in LaTeX format (with tikz inside). I would like to achieve multiple goals:

1. Separate compilation. All images can be compiled separately to their own pdf, and then included into main document.
2. No meaningless recompilations - if the image source did not change, it is not recompiled.
3. No hacks. (shell escape included)
4. One command. It must compile all images which were changed and then compile the main file.
5. Portability. The solution should work both on Windows and Linux

As I see it, I need a build system, some simple version of cmake. The question is, is there any?

Update #1:

Tried latexmk, as comments suggest. So, there are two possible ways to solve my problem:

1. Use custom dependencies feature. In my case it looks like this:

```
add_cus_dep('tex', 'pdf', 1, 'texinclude2pdf');
sub texinclude2pdf {
  system("pdflatex -synctex=1 -aux-directory \"$aux_dir\" -output-directory \"$out_dir/images\" \"$_[0].tex\"");
}
```

This solution has several problems:

- It reacts to all *.pdf includes in the main document.
- It does not allow to specify search directory for tex image files
- It is a script inside config file - why even use latexmk then?
- This script uses "system" command - it is no better than shell escape.

2. Use @default_files:

```
@default_files = ();
push @default_files, 'images/picture1.tex';
push @default_files, 'main.tex';
```

That works much better, but it does not allow to specify custom output directory (which is build/images) for image tex inputs.

Comment: There's arara -- see https://github.com/islandoftex/arara --, which may be worth looking at. That said, why not use an *actual* build system, like cmake itself?

Comment: Oh, and lest I forget: welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Seems like `tikz-externalize` should be sufficient? See the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) Section 111 _Externalizing Graphics_ on page 1178.

Comment: I suggest trying latexmk. It was explicitly designed to satisfy all your requirements.  It's part of both TeXLive and MiKTeX distributions. Under TeXLive, run `texdoc latexmk` to see the documentation.  Do I understand correctly that most/all of the tikz stuff is in the image files, not in the main document?  If so, see the section Custom Dependencies that starts at about p. 44 of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks everybody. I tried latexmk, but it does not quite work. @JohnCollins Custom dependencies feature is just not flexible enough. Futher in the question update...

Comment: Addition to @chsk's comment: You can search for questions with the `arara` tag: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arara

Answer (score 1):

I do like do use Docker+Make (or any build automation tool) to achieve this.

1. *Separate compilation*. We compile figures separately in a separate Docker container, and the document itself in another. The document will be compiled with `latexmk` (or however you want really) if needed.
2. *No meaningless recompilations*. We use GNU Make to achieve this. Figures will be rebuilt if their code changed.
3. *No hacks*. OK, you got me here.
4. *One command*. `make figures render`.
5. *Portability*. Docker is of course portable, and [GNU Make should be](https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm) but ymmv.

See [How to annoy your co-authors: a Gitlab CI pipeline for LaTeX](https://blog.martisak.se/2020/05/11/gitlab-ci-latex-pipeline/) for how to achieve this - including building using [Gitlab CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/). Using Gitlab CI here has the advantage of increasing portability.

[image: build system]

### A minimal example

The directory structure is

```
.
├── Makefile
├── images
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── image1.tex
└── main.tex
```

where the first `Makefile` contains

```
all: main.pdf

.PHONY: images
main.pdf: images

images:
    docker run -it --rm -w /data/ -v`pwd`:/data  martisak/texlive:2022 -- sh -c "make -C images"

%.pdf: %.tex
    docker run --rm -w /data/ -v`pwd`:/data martisak/texlive:2022 -- sh -c "latexmk -pdf $<"

clean:
    -make -C images clean
    latexmk -CA
    -rm -rf build
```

and `images/Makefile` contains

```
IMAGES_DIR = ../images
BUILD_DIR = ../build/images

IMAGES_TEX_FILES = $(wildcard $(IMAGES_DIR)/*.tex)
IMAGES_PDF_FILES = $(patsubst $(IMAGES_DIR)/%.tex, $(BUILD_DIR)/%.pdf, $(IMAGES_TEX_FILES))

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(IMAGES_PDF_FILES)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.pdf: $(IMAGES_DIR)/%.tex
    @mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
    latexmk -pdf -output-directory=$(BUILD_DIR) $<

clean:
    latexmk -CA
```

For completeness, `images/image1.tex` is

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle (1);
  \fill (0,0) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{An example}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{build/images/image1.pdf}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

You can omit the Docker-container if you wish, and run `latexmk` directly.

Start compilation with `make`.

Comment: I feel like this comes down to "Q: I would like a build system".  "A: Try a build automation tool."  It seems like you've hidden all of the interesting stuff in the Makefile, which isn't part of your posted answer.

Comment: @Teepeemm Valid point, I will create a simple example and edit.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I did something similar in my repos.
I wrap main build system `latexmk` with `make`, which also orchestrates images compilation as well as manages containers.
https://github.com/rudenkornk/latex_experiments